# how to know which userspace process is writing to sd card?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, usb-mass-storage

Here is the kernel stack generated using WARN_ON in sdhci_send_command**

```
*****WARNING: at /vobs/iandroid/src/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/mx_sdhci.c:495 sdhci_send_command+0x150/0x86c()
Modules linked in: g_mot_android(-) mxc91341_oh_udc sipcttydrv aplogger coredump bploader sipcdrv mu_drv
[<c0082e3c>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x14) from [<c009cda4>] (warn_slowpath+0x68/0x84)
[<c009cd3c>] (warn_slowpath+0x0/0x84) from [<c02495e0>] (sdhci_send_command+0x150/0x86c)
 r3:00000033 r2:00000000
 r7:00000000 r6:c657bf5c r5:c654a5c0 r4:c040b510
[<c0249490>] (sdhci_send_command+0x0/0x86c) from [<c024a1e0>] (sdhci_request+0x188/0x1bc)
[<c024a058>] (sdhci_request+0x0/0x1bc) from [<c02409e4>] (mmc_wait_for_req+0x1f8/0x220)
 r8:c654a400 r7:c657bef0 r6:c657bf5c r5:00001000 r4:00000001
[<c02407ec>] (mmc_wait_for_req+0x0/0x220) from [<c0247fa8>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq+0x1f4/0x7b0)
[<c0247db4>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq+0x0/0x7b0) from [<c0248a14>] (mmc_queue_thread+0x134/0x154)
[<c02488e0>] (mmc_queue_thread+0x0/0x154) from [<c00b2e88>] (kthread+0x54/0x80)
 r8:00000000 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:c02488e0 r4:fffffffc
[<c00b2e34>] (kthread+0x0/0x80) from [<c009f3a8>] (do_exit+0x0/0x738)
 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
---[ end trace 6dcb56938527653f ]---*****
```

How can I come to know which process is writing to SD card?

Comment: [fuser](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) may give you information on which processes have handles open on the SD card.

Comment: debugging on phone console. fuser not compiled into busybox. is there any other way?

Comment: [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) if available or maybe via _/proc/<pid>/fd/_